# AES encryption security provider error

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, cryptography

Ok. I have experienced this problem for quite sometime. Feeling like I am getting close, just need to be pointed in the right direction. So I am using this cool third party library called FBEncryptorAE:

```
 NSString * encryptedMessage = [FBEncryptorAES encryptBase64String:localQuery keyString:key separateLines:NO];
```

When I post this encrypted query up to my server, I get the following error:

The AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding algorithm is not supported by the Security Provider you have chosen

Here's what my constraints are:

128 bit key
AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding, Base64
coldfusion

Based off of my readings, PKCS5Padding/ PKCS7Padding are the same thing?? If someone could be kind and help me understand:

1. Why I am getting the error.
2. Is there sample code I can view based off of my constraints I have? Appreciate any help.

Comment: It's really not clear what is producing your error. Is this a Java server? Can you share the code that is trying to decrypt?

Answer (score 0):

`PKCS5Padding` and `PKCS7Padding` produce the same result for AES, are essentially the same.

If you are using `CBC` an `iv` is required. How is the `iv` made the same for both encryption on iOS and decryption on the server? `FBEncryptorAES` has `iv` capability but only for (raw data) not (base64) so it is defaulting to "nil" (from the docs). You **must** get this correct. Since `FBEncryptorAES` does not support what you need you need to use the (raw data) API and then Base64 encode with the `NSData` method `base64EncodedDataWithOptions:`.

Ensure that the `key` and `iv` are exactly the required size, for AES128 that is 16 bytes for each. Some wrappers expand undersize keys but there is no standard for that, Common Crypto does not.

Hex dump the input and outputs of all all parameters and data on both sides to ensure they match.

The problem with wrappers is that they are rather opaque as to what is actually being done and that can create interoperability problems. For this reason I always use Common Crypto and the `NSData` base64 encoding/decoding so I know exactly what is being done.

Comment: PKCS5Padding and PKCS7Padding produce the same result for all ciphers. It's just that PKCS5Padding is only defined for 8-byte block ciphers. AES is a 16-byte block cipher, so technically it shouldn't work at all. Some implementations simply call the padding PKCS5 for legacy reasons.